# chrome Pop-up blocker when to re-check after allowing page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, popup, popup-blocker

I've having app which sometimes open the popup blocker, when the user run the application chrome have some flag in the url box (right side) which tell to the user that the **pop-up is blocked** ,in this case I give to the user **in addition new warning message** like "please pay attention the page was blocked please enable it..."

My question is when and in which term I **need to do this check again** ,assume the **user allow the new App page**

> 1. if user close and open the browser does he need to enable this pop-up again ?
> 2. I know that if the user will run it in diffrent chrome versions (like canary or beta) he probably need to confirm this page again but
>      my question in which cases the pop-up will show again to the **same
>      user**(which confirm it before)
> 3. In which case **after allowing** the App to run the  pop-up blocker will block it again?

Btw I saw that in my company they add the exception to the popup blocker 
with some automated process, how it can be? there is a code that can do that?(strange...)

I see it when I click on setting search for pop -> privacy -> content settings -> manage exception and then I see 
[image]

Comment: _"I need to konw when the pop-up blocker will block specifiecd page again after user enable the page (allow it in the browser)"_ The setting should remain until removed by user. Was the setting removed when launched new instance of chrome, chromium where setting was previously set?

Comment: @guest271314 - thanks , sorry but not sure that I got this question  "Was the setting removed when launched new instance of chrome, chromium where setting was previously set? " 2. Do you know how its possible to the company to add this privacy settings ( i've addtional for my company entries domain pattern...), how this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. Do you know how its possible to the company to add this privacy settings ( i've addtional for my company entries domain pattern...),
>      how this is possible?

`Policies` can be set which override user `Preferences` set at `Settings`.

See [Documentation for Administrators](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators), follow links at [Windows Quick Start](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/windows-quick-start), [Mac Quick Start](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start), or [Linux Quick Start](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start).
Read [Configuring Other Preferences](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences), [Policy Settings in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/enterprise/adding-new-policies)

> **Should I use a Preference, or a Policy?**
>
> If you want to set some specific behavior that is accomplished by both
>   a preference and a policy, and you're not sure which one you should
>   use, simply answer: do you want users to be able to change this
>   setting?
>
> User cannot change policies at will, but they can change their
>   preferences.

---

Note, these changes to `Preferences` file should be made when chrome, chromium is closed, that is does not have an ongoing process instance to avoid a `SingletonLock` file not being created in `Default` directory a when chrome, chromium is launched again.

To set the preference at `Preferences` file in browser configuration file, for example `$ gedit ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`

```
"popups":{"[*.]domain1.com,*":{"setting":2},"[*.]domain2.com,*":{"setting":1}}
```

where `2` blocks popups, `1` allows popups, see also [`DefaultPopupsSetting`](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultPopupsSetting).

---

The icon at the right of the `Behavior` at `Pop-up exceptions` at `Settings` indicates

> *This setting is enforced by your administrator.*

Policies can applied to devices [Set Chrome policies for devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) or users [Set Chrome policies for users](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en&ref_topic=2936229) by the administrator.

The formats for policies at different platforms are

> Example value:
>
> **Windows:**
>
> ```
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\PopupsAllowedForUrls\1 = "https://www.example.com"
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\PopupsAllowedForUrls\2 = "[*.]example.edu"
> ```
>
> **Android/Linux:**
>
> ```
> ["https://www.example.com", "[*.]example.edu"]
> ```
>
> **Mac:**
>
> ```
> <array>
> <string>https://www.example.com</string>
>   <string>[*.]example.edu</string>
> </array>
> ```

For example, to create a mandatory policy for the device for popups at *nix platforms you can create a `.json` file  at `/etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/`

```
$ sudo touch /etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/popup_policy.json
$ gksudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/popup_policy.json
```

then set the popup policies for `PopupsBlockedForUrls`, `PopupsAllowedForUrls`

```
{
  "PopupsBlockedForUrls": ["[*.]example.com", "[*.]example1.com]"],
  "PopupsAllowedForUrls": ["[*.]example2.com", "[*.]example3.com]"]
}
```

When chrome, chromium is launched you can verify the policy is being enforced by navigating to

```
chrome://policy
```

where the policies should be listed; for example

```
Applies to    Level        Source      Policy name             Policy value                          Status
Machine       Mandatory    Platform    PopupsBlockedForUrls    [*.]example.com, [*.]example1.com]    OK
```

A sample policy list template is available at [policy_templates.json](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/components/policy/+/master/resources/policy_templates.json), see also [Policy Templates](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates).

Comment: Thanks ! so currently two questoin  1. so just to verify, I guess that somehow by code change the privacy setting will not be an option correct ? 2.  Regard my first question : In which case after allowing the App (from the popup blocker place right to the URL ) to run  it will block again? I mean after allowing the app to run the domain is inserted to the privacy setting and until I will not remove it manually the app will be able to run over and over again ?

Comment: @RaynD _"1. so just to verify, I guess that somehow by code change the privacy setting will not be an option correct ?"_ Not sure what you mean. User can change `Settings` when choose, though possibly not administrator `Policy` settings. _"2. In which case after allowing the App (from the popup blocker place right to the URL ) to run it will block again? I mean after allowing the app to run the domain is inserted to the privacy setting and until I will not remove it manually the app will be able to run over and over again ?"_ The setting should remain until removed by user.

Comment: I mean if I want to change the settings in javascript code i.e. add domain by code to the user...

Comment: @RaynD No. Do not believe that is possible. User action should allow or block a domain.

Comment: @RaynD User action could upload `Preferences` file to a `<textarea>` element, where user could edit file, then user could save file to same directory, to overwrite existing file. Though you cannot browse user filesystem for file, select file, edit file, then save to user filesystem using `javascript` without user action.