# Setting the page title of Chrome window.open does not work

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have some JavaScript that is being used to open a new window to print part of page I am using the window.open function and I have set the title of the page as window.open 2nd parameter (see code below),but the title appear 'about:blank' Not 'test'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
        var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, 'test', 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');


        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }
</script>
```

Note:
i know the question might be repeated but i try all answers it doesn't work for me Like:

1-Set the 1st parameter of open() to 'about:blank'

2- printWindow.document.title = 'test'

the result as shown below

[image]

Comment: what's your chrome version?

Comment: Version 54.0.2840.71 m

Comment: can you screen shot the result of your popup

Comment: i edited my question by adding screen shot to the result

Comment: in which line did you put the `printWindow.document.title` ?

Comment: before
   printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you put

```
printWindow.document.title = 'title'
```

before the `printWindow.document.write`
Solution is put `printWindow.document.title` after `printWindow.document.write`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
        var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, 'test', 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');


        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.title = 'This is the title'
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }
</script>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7790/)

Comment: Thanks a lot it take me long time to find Sol

Comment: @BentEl-Eslam if this answer solve your problem just mark this as check.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute a `data URI` of an `.html` `document` with `<title>` tag for `about:blank`, `document.write()`. Call `print()` within `<script>` tag set as last child element of `<body>` element.

```
function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
  var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var windowUrl = "data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body>" + printContent.innerHTML + "<script>print()<\/script></body></html>";
  var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, "test", 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfqHgNnjAkunJeryn71Y?p=preview

using `Blob()`, `URL.createObjectURL()` to set `window.open()` URL to `Blob URL`

```
function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
  var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body>" + printContent.innerHTML + "<script>print()<\/script></body></html>";
  var blob = new Blob([html], {type:"text/html"});
  var windowUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, "test", 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
  window.onfocus = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(windowUrl);
    printWindow.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What are `Pop-ups` settings at `Settings`? Did you click `<h1>` text content `"test"`?

Comment: No , it work for my answer but when change printPartOfPage to your it doesn't appear

Comment: Allow All site to show popup
i don't understand second question

Comment: To allow plnkr origin to open popups. Have you checked `Pop-ups` at `Setiings`? What are current browser pop-up preferences set to?

Comment: sorry, but pop-up section in settings have only 2 radio button to Allow Or not sites to show pop-ups
where i can find 'browser pop-up preferences'

Comment: @BentEl-Eslam See [chrome Pop-up blocker when to re-check after allowing page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282861/chrome-pop-up-blocker-when-to-re-check-after-allowing-page/)

Comment: i think that this is not related to my question as it's already open the window by using my code and i ask only about change page title 
so please illustrate your point of view Note:i disabled AdBlock on this page

Comment: Both `javascript` approaches open new `window` containing `document` having `title` set to `"test"` where `print()` is called, here, at chromium 52. Are pop-ups allowed at the browser you at trying at for domain plnkr?

Comment: @BentEl-Eslam What are pop-up settings for domain plnkr?

Comment: what is domain plnkr ? sorry i really doesn't get the point , i open your link [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfqHgNnjAkunJeryn71Y?p=preview) , see that Plnkr is an editor you try on it and it work , for me in my app it doesn't work and i don't know how can i get pop-up settings for domain plnkr ?

Comment: What do you by _"it doesn't work"_? Can you reproduce what does not work for you at plnkr?

Comment: plnkr is domain of editor. run.plnkr is another domain that edited pages run on.