# How to open javascript items array in a new window instead of the same window?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tabs

I have a great working code that opens a link in the same window when I click it, it's inside a dropdown menu.

This is in javascript.

problem is that I would like it to open up in a new tab instead of the same window. How can I do this?

here is my code:

```
items["linkeee"] = {
    "label": "mylabel",
    "action": function(obj) {
        openUrl('http://mypageaa.com/page' + addId);
    }
};
```

update --  also my html looks like this:

```
<a href="#">mylabel</a>
```

BUT I don't have direct access to the html without messing stuff up. I gotta  do this up there with the javascript

update

how do i combine `'http://mypageaa.com/page' + addId` to add `, "_blank"`

please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off pop-up blockers for the domain at browser preferences or settings, see  [chrome Pop-up blocker when to re-check after allowing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282861/chrome-pop-up-blocker-when-to-re-check-after-allowing-page/). Use `window.open()`

```
var w;
items["linkeee"] = {
    "label": "mylabel",
    "action": function(obj) {
        w = window.open("http://mypageaa.com/page", "_blank");
    }
};
```

Alternatively, use `<a>` element at `html` with `target` attribute set to `"_blank"`

```
<a href="http://mypageaa.com/page" target="_blank">mypageeaa</a>
```

Using `javascript`

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://mypageaa.com/pagee" + addId; // `encodeURIComponent(addId)`
a.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: i can't turn off popup blocker on other people's computers.

Comment: Use `<a>` element with `target` attribute set to `"_blank"`

Comment: how do i add the comma and other things when i also have `' + addId` after like in my question

Comment: You can create an `<a>` element, set `href`, including concatenating additional string to URL, and `target` attributes, append element to `document`, then call `.click()` on the element.

Comment: yep ___________

Comment: @server1257 _"yep (11 more characters to go)"_? Is that the string that you are trying to append to URL?

Comment: stack required more char i only wanted 3 "yep"

Comment: `<a>` element and `window.open()` are only approaches am aware of here which can achieve expected result.

Comment: how to do that with my dynamic variable

Comment: Described approach at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571989/how-to-open-javascript-items-array-in-a-new-window-instead-of-the-same-window/40572083?noredirect=1#comment68379886_40572083

Comment: sorry can you update your answer i did not understand via your comment, how do i combine `'http://mypageaa.com/page' + addId` to add `, "_blank"`

Comment: i need it inside `function(obj) {}` not outside

Comment: You can place the `javascript` approach using  `a` element within a function.

Comment: not clear can you just tell me how to combine `'http://mypageaa.com/page' + addId` with `, "_blank" `

Comment: You do not add `"_blank"` to the URL. Set `"_blank"` as value of `target` attribute of `<a>` element.

Comment: yeah i know so how can i add in my `+ addId` into your line `w = window.open("http://mypageaa.com/page", "_blank")` into that same line nothing else just your code with the dynamic variable inside

Comment: Use string concatenation `w = window.open("http://mypageaa.com/page" + addId, "_blank")`

Comment: that's what I was asking thanks, so i can just put `, "_blank" ` on the end thx

Comment: `"_blank"` should be second parameter passed to `window.open()`. Parameters passed to functions are usually separated by comma `,`

Comment: p.s. i also added `w.focus();` to the next line per another post which suggested to do that.

Answer (score 1):

use window.open instead of your openUrl method, but new window is not guaranteed to open, the browser may block it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read in the documentation and several other answers, It appears this behavior depends on user-preference / (user)browser configuration.

From JavaScript's side, there's nothing you can do to reliably open an URL in a new tab

See:
[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Documentation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the method

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace);
```

It defaults to opening a new window. (tab vs window is a user preference)

documentation [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)