# How do I create a simple solution to get around sound not autoplaying?

Tags: javascript

I am a complete noob, first question on here, so please be gentle! I'm following a basic Javascript for Sound Artists book, but the initial Hello Sound example, seems to not work due to a new need for a gesture input otherwise disabling autoplaying of sound. As I'm going to be exploring and experimenting predominantly with sound, I was wondering if anyone could please advise on a suitable and simple solution to get around this disabled sound issue? Thanks.

```
var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.type = "sine";
osc.connect (audioContext.destination);
osc.start (audioContext.currentTime);
```

Comment: _"I'm going to be exploring and experimenting predominantly with sound"_ If you are performing the experimentation, why cannot you perform the user action which precedes outputting the sound?

Comment: autoplaying sounds are evil.  users will hate you.  don't do it.

Comment: of course. I understand the interaction design principles of not bombarding people with sound, but I'm currently just trying to learn web programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to be exploring and experimenting predominantly with sound,
>   I was wondering if anyone could please advise on a suitable and simple
>   solution to get around this disabled sound issue?

You can create a separate launcher for Chromium or Chrome browsers with the appropriate flag or policy set to disable the default browser policy of disabling autoplay until user gesture.

For example

> [`--ignore-autoplay-restrictions`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ignore-autoplay-restrictions)
>
> - Ignores all autoplay restrictions. It will ignore the current autoplay policy and all restrictions such as playback in a background
>     tab. It should only be enabled for testing.

See [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: ok, this sounds like a good feature to try whilst I'm still playing.

Comment: @KarlSadler One alternative for creating a separate launcher at the OS would be to navigate to `chrome://flags` and select `"Enabled"` for `"Autoplay ignores WebAudio playbacks"` option (_"If enabled, autoplay restrictions will be ignored for WebAudio. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS"_)

Comment: I used the Chrome flag solution. That is perfect. I wasn't aware of Chrome's flag/policy features. thank you for your response. :)

Comment: @KarlSadler Note also, for clarity policies are different than flags see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282861/

Comment: --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required